# Did Nietzsche ever state “The world is beautiful, but has a disease called man”?

Tags: quotes

There's [this question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/9158/3164) on *Philosophy SE*. Nobody there has yet been able to come up with a "good" source/reference. (The thus-far apparently oldest reference, provided in a comment, is [this](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=wNVYAAAAYAAJ&q=%22the%20world%20is%20beautiful%20but%20has%20a%20disease%20called%20man%22&dq=%22the%20world%20is%20beautiful%20but%20has%20a%20disease%20called%20man%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ysHGUqauEefU0QXt6YDADQ&ved=0CGQQ6AEwCQ).) This seems like something you are quite good at and might enjoy solving.

So, despite [numerous attributions](https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=%22The%20world%20is%20beautiful,%20but%20has%20a%20disease%20called%20man%22), is there any reason to believe that Nietzsche ever said, wrote, stated, or uttered:

> The world is beautiful, but has a disease called man.

either *literally* or *literally translated*?

<sup>PS: I know that cross-posting is sometimes frowned upon. Let me know (or just put "on hold") if moderators think this is not appropriate.</sup>

Comment: I think this is an acceptable cross-post. There is no reason to believe that the expertise at Philosophy.SE is especially well suited to verify an attribution, and we do tackle these questions often here.

Answer (score 7):

The quote seems to be a paraphrase coming from Nietzche's [Zur Genealogie der Moral](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Genealogy_of_Morals/Second_Essay):

> But thereby he introduced that most grave and sinister illness, from which mankind has not yet recovered, the suffering of man from the disease called man

[image]

This was published in 1887.

In German:

> Mit ihm aber war die grösste und unheimlichste Erkrankung eingeleitet, von welcher die Menschheit bis heute nicht genesen ist, das Leiden des Menschen am Menschen, an sich

which google translates a bit differently (probably more politically correctly):

> But with him the biggest and scariest disease was initiated, of which humanity is still not recuperated, the suffering of the people on the people, per se.

According to Google N-Gram viewer, the above is the earliest usage of the idiom "disease called man".

Otherwise, you found another great source on our Philosophy site, where you also [cite](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/9158/96) another book of his [Also sprach Zarathustra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thus_Spoke_Zarathustra):

> in Thus Spake Zarathustra (section 40, "Great Events"), in the discourse with the fire-dog, Nietzsche has Zarathustra say the following:
>
> > Die Erde, sagte er, hat eine Haut; und diese Haut hat Krankheiten. Eine dieser Krankheiten heisst zum Beispiel: "Mensch." [The earth, said he, hath a skin; and this skin hath diseases. One of these diseases, for example, is called "man."]

This book was published earlier still, 1883, but uses a slightly different version of the idiom "disease called man".

Comment: That's no closer (and IMO less close) to the wanted quote than is the passage from Zarathustra which was referenced in [the question on Philosophy.SE](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/9158/4231) , i.e. `The earth, said he, hath a skin; and this skin hath diseases. One of these diseases, for example, is called "man."`

Comment: Yeah, I think the first part of the quote "the world is beautiful" is just as important in tracking this down.

Comment: As I understand this answer, you found no evidence that Nietzsche said "The world is beautiful but...". Is that correct?

Comment: "the world is beautiful" is very likely not Nietzsche. It's a common sentence. "A disease called man" instead is. The complete sentence is *attributed* to Nietzsche in all references I can find, but not in his books. Keep in mind, his books are in German...